# Loop over an shell argument which contains a list of values and write these values to a file

Tags: list, shell, loops, command-line-arguments

I have a shell script in Linux, which needs as input one argument, which can contains a list of ip adresses. These list needs to be written line by line to a file.

```
./myTestScript.sh 192.168.100.2,192.168.100.3
```

In the script, the output to be generated is

```
192.168.100.2 OK
192.168.100.3 OK
```

and written to a file called exceptions.map.

MY idea for a single IP works, but how to implement a loop ovre a list from arguments.

```
#!/bin/sh
IPADRESSES=$1
echo $IPADRESSES
sudo rm /appli/myApp/apps/mainApp/maintenance/exceptions.map
echo $IPADRESSES OK > "/appli/myApp/apps/mainApp/maintenance/exceptions.map"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a pure-bash way:

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS=, read -ra addresses <<<"$1"
for addr in "${addresses[@]}"; do
    echo "$addr OK"
done > exceptions.map
```

The `IFS=...` line reads the comma-separated contents of the first argument `$1` into array `addresses`.  They are comma-separated because of `IFS=,`.  The `for` loop then prints each address in turn, plus the OK.

Comment: I don't understand why you would use `-r` here.  If a user explicitly uses escaped newlines in the argument, it seems like they should be honored as line continuations rather than dropped.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Fair point :) .  It's my habitual practice because I haven't needed the non-`-r` case in the past.

Comment: Thanks a lot. it works as expected and is well understood how it works.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "$1" | tr , \\n | sed 's/$/ OK/' > exceptions.map
```

Or, if you really want to write a loop:

```
IFS=,
for i in $1; do
        echo "$i OK"
done
```

Note that the `$1` here must remain unquoted, since we are explicitly relying on word-splitting.  But usually, I would change the API a bit and have the caller pass each IP as a separate arugment and do `for x; do echo "$x OK"; done`.

Answer (score 1):

One command, no loop needed:

```
$ printf '%s OK\n' ${1//,/ } > "/appli/myApp/apps/mainApp/maintenance/exceptions.map"
```

`${1//,/ }` splits your command argument by replacing all commas with spaces. `printf` prints each IP according to your format.

`${1//,/ }` can also be used in a loop:

```
for ip in ${1//,/ }; do something with "$ip"; done
```